# Adding Shadows to Parallax Occlusion Map

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I've implemented Parallax Occlusion Mapping through [LearnOpengl](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Parallax-Mapping), and now **I want to add self-shadows so that the fragment extrusions throw shadows on the surface**. I've read a few papers on the topic, but I admit it's a bit advanced for me. From what I understand, it's the same process as parallax occlusion mapping, but from the light's direction instead of the view direction. I tried modifying the fragment shader, but the shadows still don't show up.

**This is how I want it to look like.**[image]
http://www.cs.utah.edu/~sujin/courses/reports/cs6610/project-report/images/pom.png

**This is the result of the modified fragment shader. Nothing changed from when it was just the parallax occlusion map.** 
[image: What I have]

Here's the modified fragment shader. I've marked that parts I added to the original parallax tutorial code.

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 o_texCoord;
in vec3 o_worldPos;
in vec3 world_normal;
in vec3 world_tangent;

out vec4 fragColor;

uniform vec3 light_pos;
uniform sampler2D diffuseMap;
uniform sampler2D normalMap;
uniform sampler2D heightMap;
uniform vec3 viewPosition;
uniform float heightScale;

vec2 ParallaxMapping (vec2 texCoord, vec3 viewDir)
{
    float minLayers = 0;
    float maxLayers = 32;
    float numLayers = mix(maxLayers, minLayers, abs(dot(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), viewDir)));
    float layerDepth = 1.0 / numLayers;

    float currentLayerDepth = 0;

    vec2 P = viewDir.xy / viewDir.z * heightScale;

    vec2 deltaTexCoords = P / numLayers;

    vec2 currentTexCoords = texCoord;

    float currentDepthMapValue = texture(heightMap, currentTexCoords).r;

    while (currentLayerDepth < currentDepthMapValue)
    {
        currentTexCoords -= deltaTexCoords;
        currentDepthMapValue = texture(heightMap, currentTexCoords).r;
        currentLayerDepth += layerDepth;
    }

    vec2 prevTexCoords = currentTexCoords + deltaTexCoords;
    float afterDepth = currentDepthMapValue - currentLayerDepth;
    float beforeDepth = texture(heightMap, prevTexCoords).r - currentLayerDepth + layerDepth;

    float weight = afterDepth / (afterDepth - beforeDepth);

    vec2 finalTexCoords = prevTexCoords * weight + currentTexCoords * (1.0 - weight);

    return finalTexCoords;
}

// FUNCTION I ADDED FOR SHADOW CALCULATION
float ShadowCalc(vec2 texCoord, vec3 lightDir)
{
    float minLayers = 0;
    float maxLayers = 32;
    float numLayers = mix(maxLayers, minLayers, abs(dot(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), lightDir)));

    float layerDepth = 1.0 / numLayers;

    float currentLayerDepth = 0;

    vec2 P = lightDir.xy / lightDir.z * heightScale;

    vec2 deltaTexCoords = P / numLayers;

    vec2 currentTexCoords = texCoord;

    float currentDepthMapValue = texture(heightMap, currentTexCoords).r;

    while (currentLayerDepth < currentDepthMapValue)
    {
        currentTexCoords -= deltaTexCoords;
        currentDepthMapValue = texture(heightMap, currentTexCoords).r;
        currentLayerDepth += layerDepth;
    }

    float r = currentDepthMapValue > currentLayerDepth ? 0.0 : 1.0;

    return r;
}

void main()
{
    mat3 TBN_norm = transpose(mat3(normalize(world_tangent),
                                   normalize(cross(world_normal, world_tangent)),
                                   normalize(world_normal)));
    vec3 viewDir = TBN_norm * normalize(o_worldPos - viewPosition);
    vec2 currentTex = ParallaxMapping(o_texCoord, viewDir);
    if (currentTex.x > 1.0 || currentTex.y > 1.0 || currentTex.x < 0.0 || currentTex.y < 0.0)
    {
        discard;
    }
    vec3 normal = texture(normalMap, currentTex).rgb;
    normal = normalize(normal * 2.0 - 1.0);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(TBN_norm * light_pos - TBN_norm * o_worldPos);
    float dc = max(0.0, dot(lightDir, normal));

    // STUFF I ADDED FOR SHADOWS
    float shadow = 0;
    if (dc > 0)
    {
        shadow = ShadowCalc(currentTex, lightDir);
    }

    fragColor = shadow * dc * texture(diffuseMap, currentTex);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the direction of the light source to the fragment in texture space is:

```c
vec3 lightDir = TBN_norm * normalize(o_worldPos - light_pos);
float dc = max(0.0, dot(-lightDir, normal));
```

To check if a fragment is in self-shadow, you have to track the ray to the light source from starting a the the "parallax" texel.

```c
float shadow = dc > 0.0 ? ShadowCalc(currentTex, lightDir) : 0.0;
```

The initial height (`currentLayerDepth`) is the height of the current fragment:

```c
float currentDepthMapValue = texture(heightMap, currentTexCoords).r;
float currentLayerDepth = currentDepthMapValue;
```

Since the depth mao is an inverse depth map (1.0 is low), a fragment is in shadow if any layer depth (`currentLayerDepth`) is less or equal the current height (`currentDepthMapValue`). The sampling has to be aborted if the maximum depth (minimum value of 0.0) is reached.
Note, that the depth is decremented (`currentLayerDepth -= layerDepth`) and the texture samples are taken in the opposite direction (`currentTexCoords += deltaTexCoords`) in compare the the `ParallaxMapping` algorithm:

```c
while (currentLayerDepth <= currentDepthMapValue && currentLayerDepth > 0.0)
{
    currentTexCoords += deltaTexCoords;
    currentDepthMapValue = texture(heightMap, currentTexCoords).r;
    currentLayerDepth -= layerDepth;
}
float r = currentLayerDepth > currentDepthMapValue ? 0.0 : 1.0;
```

Because of the division by the z-component in (`P = lightDir.xy / lightDir.z`), `P` and thus `deltaTexCoords`, points always to the light source (of course in the projection to the texture).
If the z-component of `lightDir` is grater than 0.0, the the surface is lit from the back. This results in a condition for an early abort:

```c
if ( lightDir.z >= 0.0 )
    return 0.0;
```

The full function `ShadowCalc` function may look like this:

```c
float ShadowCalc(vec2 texCoord, vec3 lightDir)
{
    if ( lightDir.z >= 0.0 )
        return 0.0;

    float minLayers = 0;
    float maxLayers = 32;
    float numLayers = mix(maxLayers, minLayers, abs(dot(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), lightDir)));

    vec2 currentTexCoords = texCoord;
    float currentDepthMapValue = texture(heightMap, currentTexCoords).r;
    float currentLayerDepth = currentDepthMapValue;

    float layerDepth = 1.0 / numLayers;
    vec2 P = lightDir.xy / lightDir.z * heightScale;
    vec2 deltaTexCoords = P / numLayers;

    while (currentLayerDepth <= currentDepthMapValue && currentLayerDepth > 0.0)
    {
        currentTexCoords += deltaTexCoords;
        currentDepthMapValue = texture(heightMap, currentTexCoords).r;
        currentLayerDepth -= layerDepth;
    }

    float r = currentLayerDepth > currentDepthMapValue ? 0.0 : 1.0;
    return r;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I understand better now. How would the implementation of soft shadows work?